# ASIHTTPRequest - Should I use multiple delegates to determine source of Async requests?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, asihttprequest

This is more of a design question. I have a single ViewController which manages a UITableView. The user can add/edit/delete items in this tableview. Changes to this tableview are persisted in my back end database via web service calls. I am using ASIHTTPRequest to wrap these web service calls.  ASIHTTPRequest requests are given a delegate object which should implement -(void)requestFinished:request and -(void)requestFailed:request.

Obviously my implementation of -(void)requestFinished:request will be different depending on whether the user is deleting a record or refreshing the tableview. How is this typically handled? Should I implement a unique delegate for different types of requests, set 'status'flags in the view controller to indicate which request is in progress or something else?

Thanks!

Comment: hey mate give the tag to every request and after check with request.tag in your delegate method.. :)

Comment: Oh nice. I didn't know about the 'tag' property. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should follow documentation of ASIHTTPRequest

Handling success and failure for multiple requests in delegate methods

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: Yes. My use case is spelled out there. Thank you!

Comment: You can differentiate each request using request.tag for individual request

Answer (score 0):

**You should give `tag` to each request you're making.**

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{

    //Here you can differentiate each request using request.tag for individual request success

}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    //Here you can differentiate each request using request.tag for individual request error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try bellow code...

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{

     if (request.tag == 1) { // 1 just an example
         /// do something here
     }
     else if (request.tag == 2) {
         /// do something here
     }
}

 - (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{

     if (request.tag == 1) { // 1 just an example
         /// do something here
     }
     else if (request.tag == 2) {
         /// do something here
     }
}
```

i hope this help you...

:)